# Customer Registration Problem with Magento. Registers Successfully, but doesn't login

Tags: magento-1.9, login, customer-account, register

I have a big issue with Customer Registration and Login(which may or may not be connected). When I try to register as a customer on my website, it goes through successfully and redirects to accounts page. However, as soon as I click anywhere to edit any information or check any further detailed information about my account, it redirects to login page, and I can't login at all.

I tried to check at the admin panel, if the account was registered (customers>manage customers), and the account is shown on the table of all the customer accounts. However, if I click on any customer to view or change edit the customer details, I face Fatal error as follows :

**Fatal error: Call to a member function setDisabled() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/tiendasagatha.co.uk/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Account.php on line 83**

Also, if I try to add a new customer from the add new customer option (Admin Panel : Customers > Manage Customers), I face the fatal error as follows :

**Fatal error: Call to a member function addClass() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/tiendasagatha.co.uk/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Account.php on line 87**

I have another magento website, where it works just fine and I copy/pasted the Account.php file from there to the site that I'm facing this problem with, but it didn't help either.

Can anyone suggest a fix to this?

Comment: Thanks Really Great answer. i solve my using query with out any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has something to do with `website_id` attribute of customer.

- Check whether `website_id` column is there in `customer_entity` table and check values are correctly entered for your customers.
- It requires `website_id` should be there in all customer forms. Magento renders admin customer edit form using `Mage_Eav_Model_Form` with a form code `adminhtml_customer`. So if the customer attribute `website_id` is removed from this form, then it is possible to get this error.

### EDIT

In order to make sure, there is nothing wrong with customer form related to `website_id`, you need to look into the table `customer_form_attribute`. There should be an entry corresponds to `website_id` with a form code `adminhtml_customer`.

To get the `attribute_id` corresponds to `website_id` attribute, you can use this query

> SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE entity_type_id IN (SELECT
>   entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code =
>   'customer') AND attribute_code="website_id";

Now check this attribute_id is present in `customer_form_attribute` table for an attribute code `adminhtml_customer`.

If it is also looks good, then you can try your luck with below query:

> UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET entity_type_id = 1 WHERE attribute_code =
>   "website_id";

**PS:** Take backup of your db, if you want to run last query.

Comment: I just confirmed that customer_entity table does have website_id column in there. How do I check if the values are correctly entered for the customers?

Comment: check `website_id` column value for last entries.

Comment: The most recent one is "NULL" however, the two prior to that are 1. (There are only 3 entries in the table)

Comment: so that means, customers are not saving correctly. It should be 1 as like very first entry.

Comment: That's what I think as well. The registration page isn't working, and like I have already mentioned in the question, the Manual Admin Page Customer Registration results in fatal error mentioned in the question. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: see my edit. there is something wrong with customer saving action. you need to dig it out somehow.

Comment: I tried to use the first SQL query that you suggested in the EDIT, and it resulted in an Empty set.

Comment: `SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE entity_type_id IN (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'customer') AND attribute_code="website_id";` are you mentioning this query ? If yes, this means `website_id` is now not an attribute for customer in your site. So you require to execute the last query `UPDATE eav_attribute SET entity_type_id = 1 WHERE attribute_code = "website_id";` in order to remove this issue

Comment: I made the changes suggested by you, and now it works like a charm. I can't thank you enough! Many cheers!

Comment: Please accept this answer if it helps you and thank me with a beer if we meet :)

Comment: Amen to that!..